# Issuing PKCS11 token from PKCS12 keystore

Tags: java, security, pkcs#11

I'm having trouble issuing certificate to a hard token, What I have is a PKCS12 keystore I have created and want to move it to a hardtoken as a PKCS11.

I can successfully generate keys and certificate and save them in a p12 keystore and can import the p12 file to hardtoken using admin console of this device. 
But when I try to do the final step programatically I have different result.

**Imported p12 file using admin tool what I have in device is**
-Serial number
  -Signature and key exchange usage
      Certificate
      Private Key
      Public key

**Imported all steps programatically**
-Serial number
  -Signing &encryption
      Certificate
      Private Key

and the final result is that end user can't use the device for signing.
I'm using SunPKCS11.

**Edit:** Code used for importing the key:

```
KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry priEntry = 
    new KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry(keys.getPrivate(), certificateArray); 
KeyStore.PasswordProtection password = 
    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(pass.toCharArray()); 
store.setEntry("Entry", priEntry, password);
```

**EDIT 2** keytool -list

The funny thing is that when I use the following command output is the very same
keytool -keystore NONE -storetype pkcs11 -list

Comment: How do you identified the difference between the original cert and the imported one?

Comment: oops,  
thanks for edit, I've removed the comments.  
Regarding the differences, I can see the difference in token manager application. The code seems to be fine but the result is not what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Is it possible that PKCS11 attributes make such difference? I've gone through them and tested what I thought may make a difference but found nothing. 
Maybe someone can shed a light?